# Using Page Definition Query?

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I'm looking to use data driven pages to automate some of my workflow, and I'm almost there for the most part.

I have a layer (Chainage - 200m markers along a watercourse) that I'm trying to perform a Page Definition Query on, but with no success. The chainage layer and index layer both share a field ('system' - sort of an in-house code for the watercourse). However when I set that as my field to query on, I have no chainage features appearing at all. The problem is, I can see that the system number is the definitely the same in the chainage layer and the index layer as it is displayed on my map page via dynamic text.

Comment: If the field type the same in both feature classes?

Comment: What field stores page name?

Comment: @Tom - Both have the Text field type.

Comment: @FelixIP - does the page name field need to be in my Chainage layer? The page name field is currently in my Index file. It is called 'item', each page is an item of work.

Comment: EDIT - I believe the problem was that I did not have the page name field in my Chainage layer, however doing this now presents a new problem. Some of the Items of work fall in the same watercourse, and so by putting one Item number in the chainage layer, they would not appear for another Item.

To clarify - Items 101 and 102 are both works along River A. In order to have the Chainage layer appear on the page for 101, it would mean that it would not appear in 102.

Comment: Field names can be different, but values must match for page definition to work. Duplicate item if it belongs to two pages.

Comment: This is difficult to follow and the answer below sounds way off.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue some time ago, when I wanted to use page numbers. I then switched to page names instead and it worked properly afterwards. Hope it helps!